# Which InitialContextFactory should I use?

Tags: java, ejb, openejb, apache-tomee

I am working on an EJB 3 project using OpenEJB (TomEE++).

I have a stateless session bean whose name has been specified with an annotation.

```
@Stateless(mappedName="SlideService", name="SlideService")
public class SlideService {

    public Map<Category, List<SlideShow>> fetchSlideShowsByCategory() {
        Application app = Application.getInstance();
        return app.retreiveAllSlideShowsByCategory();
    }

    public SlideShow fetchSlideShow(long id) {
        return null;
    }

    public List<SlideShow> fetchSlideShowsByTitle(String title) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I lookup the Session bean from my Struts action class, like this.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(properties);
SlideService slideService = (SlideService)initialContext.lookup("SlideServiceLocalBean");
```

In the code above you will notice that I have to use the name 'SlideServiceLocalBean', to locate the bean, whereas I have explicitly specified 'SlideService' in the bean's annotation.

However, when I try to locate the bean in my test case I have to use yet another name string.

```
EJBContainer ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
Object oSlideService = ejbContainer.getContext().lookup("java:global/slides/SlideService");
```

Why is there a discrepancy in lookup names ?

Am I obtaining the InitialContext in the right way, in the Struts action class, or should I use another mechanism/contextFactory to get the initial context ?

Is it possible to have the bean injected in the action class without using an external DI library  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this inside your struts action class:

```
new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/slides/SlideService");
```

It should work fine.  So should this from inside the action class:

```
new InitialContext().lookup("java:module/SlideService");
```

The lookup using the `LocalInitialContextFactory` predates JavaEE 6 Global JNDI where these `java:global` and `java:module` names come from.

This doc explains how it works.

- http://openejb.apache.org/jndi-names.html

Your bean's name is `SlideService` and has what is called an `@LocalBean` view (a single bean can have many views such as @LocalBean, @Remote, @Local), so the name for looking up the SlideService as an `@LocalBean` ends up being `SlideServiceLocalBean`

That's just the default format.  You can change it to whatever you like in the `conf/system.properties` file.

Comment: Nit sure why, but when I try the first option, I get an Exception "SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/slides] threw exception [javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name slides is not bound in this Context] with root cause
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name slides is not bound in this Context"